# How to create an index for custom environments?

Tags: environments, indexing

I have defined a custom script environment, and would like to include an index in the output listing all scripts with their titles. How can I create such an index?

The custom environment looks like:

```
\newcounter{script}
\def\thescript{\thechapter-\arabic{script}}
\newenvironment{script}[2][]{
\colorbox{orange}
  {\refstepcounter{script}\textbf{Script~\thescript #1: #2}}\nobreak}
  {}
```

Comment: A few details could be helpful. How did you create that environment? Is it a float environment like `figure` or `table`?

Comment: Added my custom environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the [`tocloft`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) package. There is, in particular, a `\newlistof` command to do exactly what you're looking for. Read section 2.4 of it's documentation for the full details (on how to make it work with your own environment).

Comment: Works like a charm! thanx!