# \ref giving incorrect number for \label in custom environment

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering, environments

I have defined a custom environment (using the *tocloft* package, [thanx to Juan](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3899/how-to-create-an-index-for-custom-environments)) that looks like:

```
\newcommand{\listscriptname}{List of Scripts}
\newlistof[chapter]{script}{spt}{\listscriptname}
\def\thescript{\thechapter-\arabic{script}}
\newenvironment{script}[2][]
  { \vspace{3mm}\hspace{3mm}
    \colorbox{orange}{\refstepcounter{script}
    \textbf{Script~\thescript #1:code/#2.groovy}}
    \addcontentsline{spt}{script}
       {\protect\numberline{\thescript}#1~~code/#2.groovy}
  }
  {}
```

which I use like:

```
\begin{script}{FooBar}
\label{script:FooBar}
BitStream.
\end{script}
```

And refer to it with:

```
Script~\ref{script:FooBar}.
```

But instead of the script environment number, I get the number of the section.

What am I doing wrong (I did try several variations...)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Move `\refstepcounter` out of the `\colorbox`:

```
\newenvironment{script}[2][]
  {\vspace{3mm}\hspace{3mm}%
    \refstepcounter{script}%
    \colorbox{orange}{%
    \textbf{Script~\thescript foo#1bar:code/#2.groovy}}
    \addcontentsline{spt}{script}
       {\protect\numberline{\thescript}#1~~code/#2.groovy}
  }
  {}
```

Comment: Of course... yes, makes sense... in retrospect at least... :) Thanx!