# Own table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents

Is it possible to introduce an own table of contents in LaTeX?
I would like to introduce an own tag, to define some terms in my document.
At the end of the document I would like to automatically generate a list of defined terms, with links to the page, where the term was defined.

Comment: Will you only have one reference to the item (at it's first usage/definition)?

Comment: Have a look at [How to create an index for custom environments?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3899/how-to-create-an-index-for-custom-environments), if you really mean something like a table of contents. Otherwise you could clarify if you mean an index, a glossary or nomenclature, because there are packages for this.

Comment: Which documentclass do you use? Please provide a minimal example.

Comment: You don't have to mention LaTeX in the title. It's the default on this site. What you mean is normally called list-of-X or maybe an index.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the following example I defined a `\Defi` command with two mandatory arguments; the first mandatory argument for the term to be defined and the second one, for the definition; the command typesets the term in boldfaced font, adds the term to the auxiliary file `.def`, and adds a `\phantomsection` command (this part requires the `hyperref` package) to get the proper anchor for the hyperlinks. The command `\listofdefinitions` will actually create the new "List of Definitions" using the kernel `\@starttoc` command. In the example the entries of the new list will be formatted as the figures in the LoF, but this can also be customized:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand\Defi[2]{%
  \noindent\makebox[1.5cm][l]{%
    \textbf{#1}%
    \phantomsection% comment out if hyperref is noy used
    \addcontentsline{def}{figure}{#1}}{#2}\par}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\listdefinitionname{List of Definitions}
\newcommand\listofdefinitions{%
  \section*{\listdefinitionname}\@starttoc{def}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\Defi{CDMA}{Code Division Multiple Access}
\Defi{GSM}{Global System for Mobile communication}
\Defi{NAD}{Nicotinamide Adenine Dinucleotide}
\Defi{TDMA}{Time Division Multiple Access}
\Defi{IC}{Integrated Circuit}
\Defi{BUT}{Block Under Test}

\listofdefinitions

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's a version of the above code using the `\newlistof` command from the [tocloft](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand\Defi[2]{%
  \noindent\makebox[1.5cm][l]{%
    \phantomsection% comment out if hyperref is noy used
    \textbf{#1}%
    \addcontentsline{def}{figure}{#1}}{#2}\par}

\newcommand\listdefinitionname{List of Definitions}
\newlistof{definition}{def}{\listdefinitionname}

\begin{document}

\Defi{CDMA}{Code Division Multiple Access}\newpage
\Defi{GSM}{Global System for Mobile communication}
\Defi{NAD}{Nicotinamide Adenine Dinucleotide}\newpage
\Defi{TDMA}{Time Division Multiple Access}
\Defi{IC}{Integrated Circuit}
\Defi{BUT}{Block Under Test}

\listofdefinition

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thnx for the nice solution! Is it somehow possible to sort the `listofdefinitions` before printing it?

Comment: @Skip: if you want to sort the entries, perhaps you could better consider using a package such as [nomencl](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/nomencl).

Answer (score 1):

@Gonzalo Medina: Putting `\addcontentsline` in `\makebox` slows down processing. And the abbreviation may sometimes be longer than the fixed `1.5cm` you have used.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\Defi[2]{%
  \noindent
  \makebox[\ListOfDefAbbrevLength][l]{\textbf{#1}}%
    \csname phantomsection\endcsname
    \addcontentsline{def}{figure}{#1}%
  {#2}\par
}
\newdimen\ListOfDefAbbrevLength
\ListOfDefAbbrevLength=1.5cm
\newcommand\ListOfDefName{List of Definitions}
\newcommand\ListOfDefinitions{%
  \section*{\ListOfDefName}%
  \@starttoc{def}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\Defi{CDMA}{Code Division Multiple Access}
\Defi{GSM}{Global System for Mobile communication}
\Defi{NAD}{Nicotinamide Adenine Dinucleotide}
\Defi{TDMA}{Time Division Multiple Access}
\Defi{IC}{Integrated Circuit}
\Defi{BUT}{Block Under Test}

\ListOfDefinitions

\end{document}
```