# Parsing some buzzwords in the Latex document and replacing them by link possible?

Tags: links, parsing, keywords

Is it possible to parse the whole document automatically, looking for buzzwords (which I will maintain in a special list), and replace the buzzwords with links to a predefined page e.g. a glossary?

Comment: Automatically? Your editor should provide a search-and-replace feature so you can find these words and modify them (to whatever) as you like. Since this seems too straight-forward an answer, I assume you actually mean something else. Please elaborate and provide an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [How to highlight keywords?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22598/how-to-highlight-keywords).

Comment: Also a possible duplicate of [Own table of contents?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38335/own-table-of-contents), since you want to define a term and reference it somewhere. The hyperlink is from the "Glossary" though, not from within the text.

Comment: Perhaps TeX is not the right tool. How about sed/awk?

Comment: Its not a duplicate of Own table of contents. I would like to define a list if buzzwords and I would like any occurence of thebuzzwords to link to a special page - the glossar page.
I dont want to explicitely mark every occurence by a tag like in the table of contents.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible with XeTeX and the package `xesearch` that works with Plain XeTeX, XeLaTeX and ConTeXt.

However I think it's better to mark the document, by saying something like

```
\buzzword{Hello}
```

that will make your intentions clearer.

Comment: Thnx for the tipp with XeTeX. Marking every occurence of teh word is not a solution for me. I want every every occurence to be marked automagically, because I have a long list and the words occur in the text really often.